# Errors with shininess

Tags: java, opengl, minecraft

I am working on a Minecraft mod, and I am attempting to make a gun gold when a specific person is logged on. I have everything worked out, except for the shininess itself. I used the code from [this site](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjAC&url=http://devernay.free.fr/cours/opengl/materials.html&ei=sj6lU4K0DsTKkwW37oGgDQ&usg=AFQjCNHMOpbzamWwsAsnDQg3mwF3Vf3kBw&sig2=4sek08q3LGwZBGfvEF-2WA&bvm=bv.69411363,d.dGI) to get the Ambient, Specular, Diffuse and Shininess of Gold, but when I run the game, I get this error:

```
GL11.glMaterialf(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_AMBIENT, 0.24725f);
GL11.glMaterialf(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, 0.75164f);
GL11.glMaterialf(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_SPECULAR, 0.628281f);
GL11.glMaterialf(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_SHININESS, 0.4f);
```

I copied the code from the site, but I did not feel like using a shader, so I tried writing it out as OpenGL code (as you can see above). However, when the gun renders, it colours gold (because I write the color code), but it does not shine, and this error is printed into the console:

```
2014-06-21 18:27:36 [SEVERE] [Minecraft-Client] ########## GL ERROR ##########
2014-06-21 18:27:36 [SEVERE] [Minecraft-Client] @ Post render
2014-06-21 18:27:36 [SEVERE] [Minecraft-Client] 1280: Invalid enum
```

Does anyone have any ideas? This obviously isn't a question about Minecraft modding, but more about the OpenGL rendering.

(btw, it is rendering with LWJGL and Java 6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because `GL_AMBIENT`, `GL_DIFFUSE` and `GL_SPECULAR` are not valid arguments for `glMaterialf()`. Those define *RGBA vectors* of material coefficients, not just a single scalar value like you try set. You have to use `glMaterialfv()` instead and specify 4 components per parameter. The table you linked already maks this very clear by having 3 values (RGB) per parameter, they just ignor the alpha component, which isn't really relevent for the material itself, but you still have to specify one.

But I also have to warn you that the result will still not look too realistic unless some reflection technics are used, like environment mapping.

Comment: "But I also have to warn you that the result will still not look too realistic unless some reflection technics are used, like environment mapping." - have you ever seen Minecraft? :-)

Comment: @GuyRT: yes, I have. Didn't impress me at all. :)

Comment: Also, 0.4 is a very small value for `GL_SHININESS`. It will not really make your material appear shiny. For a shiny material, you will want to use a value that is maybe 30.0 for moderately shiny to 100.0 for really shiny.

Comment: actually, the linked site itself gives a useage example, and explains that the listed shininess value is to be multiplied by 128.

Comment: Nevermind, I don't feel like going the long way, as it is a user specific feature. Thanks for the help anyway guys!